# Actual size of Blob in App Engine Datastore

Tags: java, database, google-app-engine

I use the `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Blob` type in my web-application. As it's mentioned in reference the size of such entity is "Up to 1 megabyte".

The question is: if I wrap a byte array of size less then 1 megabyte (e.g. 500 KB) into this entity - what would be the actual size of the entry in database - the real size (500 KB) or the maximum size (1MB)?

Comment: Well, what do you think? Would a programmer allow such waste?

Comment: Let's just remember that `CHAR(200)` entry in Oracle database will be of 200 size even if we put 100-character string inside.

Comment: You're right. But, I think it will scale when required. Hence the `Up to...`.

Comment: I think so too, but I want to know for sure :) Unfortunately I can't find any official notes about this case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be the actual size of the data. You can tell by looking at the blob viewer in your admin panel.

Comment: Thanks! That's what we thought with @AljoshaBre

Comment: The Blob viewer is for viewing blobstore blobs, not datastore blob fields.

Comment: You are correct sir, I didn't notice that he was referencing the datastore blob type.